# Why is my gravity script repelling and not attracting?

Tags: unity, physics, simulations

I'm currently working on a [small simulation](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/Gravity-Simulator) of Newton's Law of Gravitation in Unity3d, and it seems to be working pretty well, except, it's doing the opposite of what I expected. Instead of attracting as it should, this script is repelling objects instead:

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Gravity component.
/// </summary>
public class GravityComponent : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float gravityConstant;
    public Vector3 startingForce;
    public GameObject twinObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies attraction to the object.
    /// </summary>
    public void ApplyAttraction()
    {
        Vector3 currentForce = this.transform.position - this.twinObject.transform.position;
        float attraction = 
              ((this.gravityConstant * this.rigidbody.mass * this.twinObject.rigidbody.mass)
            / (Mathf.Pow(currentForce.magnitude, 2)));
        this.rigidbody.AddForce(currentForce * attraction);
    }

    public void Start()
    { this.rigidbody.AddForce(this.startingForce); }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    { this.ApplyAttraction(); }
}
```

While it is possible to "fix" this by making the result of the attraction calculation negative as seen below, this solution feels "dirty", as it's not truly following Newton's Law of Gravitation.

```
float attraction = 
      -((this.gravityConstant * this.rigidbody.mass * this.twinObject.rigidbody.mass)
    / (Mathf.Pow(currentForce.magnitude, 2)));
```

What's the issue here? Is there a way to solve this issue without the above "dirty" fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, while your variable may be named `currentForce`, it actually only contains the vector pointing from `this` to `this.twinObject`. Furthermore, with your addition, the subtraction actually points **toward** the first object. Think of vector a in this image to be your `this.transform.position` and vector b as your `this.twinObject.transform.position`.

[image: Vector Substraction]

So, since the vector is pointing **from** b **to** a, the vector is pointing in the opposite direction of the direction you actually want a to go in. You want to be going **toward** b.

To fix this just subtract b - a instead of a - b:

```
Vector3 currentForce = this.twinObject.transform.position - this.transform.position;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Vector3 currentForce = this.transform.position - this.twinObject.transform.position;
```

This gets you a vector pointing from `twinObject` toward yourself. By applying a force in that direction, you end up pushing yourself *away* from `twinObject`.

Think of it using one-dimensional numbers:

```
int difference = 5 - 2;
//difference is now 3
//difference points from 2 toward 5
```

Your solution multiplies `currentForce` by negative one, which flips the direction back to match your desired result. It's a minor kludge, but it works in a pinch. When I find myself doing that, I usually figure I've flipped the direction of a vector accidentally.

You can also fix this by flipping the operands for the subtraction:

```
Vector3 currentForce = this.twinObject.transform.position - this.transform.position;
```